# How to Setdate in DateBox?

Tags: google-apps-script, datebox

I have a little problem with my DateBox in Html Service Google app Script.
First, my Database is a Google Spreadsheet.
I have create a form with html service, and i need to update my form. I display my Database by my form. (My form display one row of my DB)
I don't know if it's possible but, i like to set a date at my DateBox ?

I hope to be clear.

Comment: I'm confused what you are asking here. Do you want to set the value of a cell from the date selected using a Datebox or set the date on the Datebox from the value already specified in the database/Google sheet?

Comment: Sorry to not be clear, i want set the date on the DateBox from the value already specified in the DB.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Have you got any code written already that you are having issues with that you could show us? Or are you unsure on where to start?

Comment: I'm on since few month, it's a big project. I show you a part of code :     <div class="date"><label>Next Date : </label><input type="date" name="next" id="dd" value="<?=tab[5]?>"/></div>                                           tab[5] is a value of my DB (Thu Dec 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) that return this value)

Comment: The reason it is not working is because you need to convert the current date and time to a format that will work with the HTML DateBox. The format it yyyy-mm-dd Example: <input type="date" name="bday"  value="1981-12-28"> This will set "28/12/1981" So just convert the date in the cell to the HTML format using Google Script. Done!

Answer (score 0):

To convert the date in Apps Script to the format the datebox can use you can use the Utilities.formatDate() method.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)

It uses SimpleDateFormat for the formatting string. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
var date = new Date('Thu Dec 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)');
var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT+0100', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
Logger.log(newDate); // returns 11/12/2014
```

There is also a momentjs library for Apps Script:
MHMchiX6c1bwSqGM1PZiW_PxhMjh3Sh48

see momentjs.com for documentation

Comment: thank everyone, i think i find a good solution, i can shiw you if you want.